# Unable to install cloudflared on RPi3

Tags: raspberrypi, binary

I am trying to setup a R-Pi 3 running on Ubuntu server as a pi-hole :

```
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1014-raspi2 #16-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 11:18:23 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have installed the pi-hole using the single install command. No issues.

But tried installing the `cloudflared` service on it, through multiple articles but overall by these steps:

```
wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/VdrWdbjqyF/cloudflared-stable-linux-arm.tgz
tar -xvzf cloudflared-stable-linux-arm.tgz
sudo cp ./cloudflared /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloudflared
cloudflared -v
```

but on the last command I always get the error saying: `-bash: /usr/bin/cloudflared: No such file or directory`

I have tried multiple articles for installation and looked for this error. But nothing seems to help with not much ways to find the issue here either.

Enabling DoH is something I want to get working and this issue seems so obscure.

What could be the issue here?

--edit--
requested details:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

and,

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/cloudflared
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36928876 Dec  9 23:51 /usr/bin/cloudflared
```

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/cloudflared
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36928876 Dec 13 20:29 /usr/local/bin/cloudflared
```

PS: cloudflared present at both directories from previous tries. Should I remove it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to include `echo $PATH` and `ls -l /usr/bin/cloudflared`?

Comment: added the outputs for the above commands

Comment: What happens if you try `/usr/local/bin/cloudflared`?

Comment: getting the same message. No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have the binary for the wrong arm architecture. If you run the `file` command on the binary you should see something like this for arch64:

```
# file /usr/bin/cloudflared
/usr/bin/cloudflared: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1,
BuildID[sha1]=da09ab5a10be675f43fde2ce9aecf7cd2bab6d5c, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0,
stripped
```